# Find common values in dictionary that has keys with multiple values

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am new to python and I have a problem. I am trying to find keys with a value; however, the keys have multiple values.

```
d = {
    'a': ['john', 'doe', 'jane'], 
    'b': ['james', 'danny', 'john'], 
    'C':['john', 'scott', 'jane'],
}
```

I want to find the value `john` in d and get the keys a, b and c or find `jane` and get keys a and c.

Comment: If this is really what you want to do, your dictionary is upside down. If you're going to lookup by names (e.g. `john`), those should be the keys.

Comment: @idjaw I tried the following code. I didn't work at all.
for name in d.keys():
    if d[name] == 'john':
        print name

Comment: @import.zee The reason that code doesn't work is that the values are lists of multiple names, rather than individual name strings. So you can't test `if d[name] == 'john'` because `['john', 'doe', 'jane'] != 'john'`. Instead you need to use the `in` list memebership test operator: `if 'john' in d[name]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can easily be done using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It iterates over every key/value pair from the dict's items list, which contains all key/value pairs (`for key,val in d.items()`) and selects only the pairs where the target string is contained in the value list (`if 'john' in val`), building a list out of the resulting keys (`[ key ... ]`).

```
>>> [ key for key,val in d.items() if 'john' in val ]
['b', 'a', 'C']
>>> [ key for key,val in d.items() if 'jane' in val ]
['a', 'C']
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have to go through the dictionary items and if the find keyword is in the item list then the corresponding key has to be stored in a list and this list has to be displayed.

```
d = {'a':['john', 'doe', 'jane'], 'b': ['james', 'danny', 'john'], 'C':['john', 'scott', 'jane'],}
find ='jane'
```

So this is how the logic is written in python

```
print ([m for m in d.keys() if find in d[m]])
```

And it will give the following output

```
['a', 'C']
```